# How to match a 4 character long term that contains 0 or more letters and at least 1 number

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex:

```
codes = re.findall(r"\">([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}) ", source_code)
```

This returns any 4 character terms that made up of numbers or letters, however I would like to return only the terms that contain at least one number. Can someone show me the code I should be using instead?

Comment: Using positive lookahead: https://regex101.com/r/mUIBGy/6

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/qpOYDu/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the one, using [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\">(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z\d]{4})
```

Test cases at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hr87wi/2).

But, an easier approach to understand is, you can first catch by your current regex, then check if the result contains at least 1 number by using `\d+` regex.

Runnable Python program [here](https://repl.it/MWFh/2):

```
import re

regex = r"\">(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z\d]{4})"

test_str = ("\">abcda\n"
    "\">1111a\n"
    "\">ab1da\n"
    "\">abc2a\n"
    "\">3bcda\n"
    "\">a2cda")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
  print (match.group(1))
```

Comment: OP said 0 or more letters, so you only need lookahead for the numbers.

Comment: Yes. I see. I was editing while you were commenting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, and I'm curious as there are two lots of parenthesis in the regex. Is this a typo?